# math.pow in method results to an error

Tags: java, methods

could anyone please explain why the following method doesn't work and returns the following error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: "

```
class Example01 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(myExp(2));
   }
     double myExp(int x) {
     return Math.pow(x,2);
     }
}
```

I thought it might be for using int variable in Math.pow but I tried it this way without setting up a method and it worked ok:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2,2));
```

Could someone please give a bit of a flavour on why the method fails to return the result?

Many thanks,
Vlad

Comment: only problem i see is your `myExp` should be a static function

Comment: According to Java documentation `Math.pow(double, double)`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

Answer (score 0):

change the method `double myExp(int x)` to `static double myExp(int x)`.

Answer (score 0):

method `double myExp(int x)` should be static.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare myExp static.

```
 static double myExp(int x) {
    return Math.pow(x,2);
 }
```

or you can instantiate a Example01 class and call the function.

```
class Example01 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example01 ex = new Example01();
    System.out.println(ex.myExp(2));
  }
  double myExp(int x) {
    return Math.pow(x,2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java all the non-static method are instance method i.e. they require an instance or an object to be called upon.Either declare your `myExp(int x)` method static i.e. `static double myExp(int x)` or instantiate your class to create an object and then call `myExp(int x)` on it i.e.

```
 class Example01 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Example01 example = new Example01();
System.out.println(example.myExp(2));
}
double myExp(int x) {
return Math.pow(x,2);
}
}
```